# 500px API POST oauth/access_token

Tags: c#, api, oauth, uwp, 500px

I'm facing with 500px login API and having troubles with oauth process.

The call to oauth/access_token always fails with 401 code.

The same library, code lines, works great with all other services like Twitter, Facebook etc and also I've tested signature function with third party tools and it works, confirmed by the fact it works for other API.
I tried both sending verifier code and xauth, but nothing.

As post parameters I send:

```
oauth_verifier=nB9IpquPRJ42yJmfr9Rp
```

Into Auth post header I send the following parameters:

```
oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMER_KEY", 
oauth_nonce="42419765", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",                      
oauth_signature="vEFaeahLWX9MO0dc1G2a9Gc7Dec%3D", 
oauth_timestamp="1444381468", 
oauth_token="XTL7PIwiawt6zMgJuggxajgRWID6nEM77nHwBXDM", 
oauth_version="1.0"
```

That's all...

Said that it should be the standard procedure, Is there something wrong in my flow or something different I have to do with 500px API?

Comment: If I was you I wouldn't post my token publicly.

Comment: Maybe this older example could help? http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/exploring-oauth-c-and-500px/

Comment: Do your calls to request_token and authorize endpoints return successfully?

Comment: Yes, request_token return succeffully ruturning token and secret codes